# Корутины выполняются в одном потоке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Короткий вопрос по asincio: Корутины выполняются в одном потоке?

Всегда разные треды, всегда один тред или потоки выделяются по необходимости? Зависит ли это от реализации `loop`?

Этот вопрос связан с использованием `threading.local`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Да.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading):

> An event loop runs in a thread and executes all callbacks and tasks in the same thread.

`asyncio.get_event_loop()` возвращает цикл событий соответствующий текущему контексту. По умолчанию это текущий поток, то есть [один цикл на поток](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#event-loop-policies-and-the-default-policy). При вызове из coroutine, [возвращается цикл, который эту coroutine выполняет](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c6ce8fba07ea6798eac46ab2808167afecd4d90b/Lib/asyncio/events.py#L664-L676):

> When called from a coroutine or a callback (e.g. scheduled with call_soon
>   or similar API), this function will always return the running event loop.

Большинство методов и классов в `asyncio` не являются потокобезопасными. Если хотите из другого потока запустить задачу в цикле, то можно использовать [asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe).

Даже в одном потоке могут быть проблемы с изменением нелокального состояния при возвращении контроля циклу событий (`await`). См., [PEP 550 -- Execution Context](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0550/). В Питоне 3.7 доступен [`contextvars` модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html), реализующий [PEP 567 -- Context Variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0567/).

Comment: можно уточнить? т.е. event loop работает как один процесс? не используя все ядра процессора? просто не могу тогда понят почему по диспетчеру задач нагрузка идет на все ядра при работы одного срипта

Comment: @garrythehotdog то что сам цикл событий в одном потоке не значит, что не может быть запущен код в других процессах/потоках, к примеру посредством `asyncio.create_subprocess*` (внешние команды), `loop.run_in_executor()` (выполнить блокирующий/C код в пуле процессов/потоков)

Comment: т.е. по идее я могу создать несколько процессов(через multiprocessing) и в каждом создать совой eventloop?

Comment: @garrythehotdog: цикл событий ровно **один** в сценариях, описанных в комментарии.

Comment: я только что протестировал, создал 4 процесса и в каждом из них создал свой eventloop

Comment: @garrythehotdog: не всё что можно сделать, следует делать. Ни в ответе ни в своих комментариях *нигде* я не предлагал использовать больше одного цикла событий.

Comment: так, а почему Вы считаете что это плохо? если есть 4 ядра, не логично ли их использовать все?

Comment: @garrythehotdog если это ещё не ясно  из предыдущих комментариев: вовсе не нужно заводить несколько циклов событий, чтобы использовать несколько CPU ядер.

Comment: если честно, то не ясно...как я понимаю, создание разных циклов событий в разных процессах должно ускорить работу, так как будет меньше блокировок, разве я не прав?

Comment: @garrythehotdog если у вас есть конкретная проблема с производительностью, то задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос специально об этом. Начните с минимального примера кода  который демонстрирует проблему, измерьте  производительность. Вы должны по меньшей мере быть способны ответить на вопрос является ли ваша задача I/O bound или CPU bound.